# AutoHotKey How to send keys when pressing crtl+shift+1+2

Tags: autohotkey

I want to send keys when pressing

`crtl+shift+1+2`
`crtl+shift+1+3`
`crtl+shift+1+4`

But how do I execute a shortcut with two numbers?

`^+12::Send ...` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#If ( GetKeyState("ctrl") && GetKeyState("shift") )  ; && means logical-AND

     1 & 2::MsgBox, crtl+shift+1+2
     1 & 3::MsgBox, crtl+shift+1+3

#If ; turn off context sensitivity
```

See [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo), [GetKeyState()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm#function),  [#If directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm), and [& operator](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#operators) in the documentation.